# How do I update a label in a different view controller?

Tags: swift, swift5

I’m very new to coding. I created a game and there is a `scoreLabel` in the top corner of `GameViewController`. I created another label in a different view controller (`ShopViewController`) called `moneyLabel`. I want the money label to be equal to the score. I made it so that my score label resets every time you start a new game, but I want my money to stay the same so that I can use the money for purchases in game.

I don’t know how to make it update. I tried: `gameViewController = GameViewController()` and then using code to update my label but it’s not working. My label isn’t updating at all. It stays at 0.

Comment: You can change a label of previous viewcontroller just by calling it. You need to create a protocol to change the label of previous viewcontroller (GameViewController), like this https://medium.com/@ales.musto/simple-example-of-using-a-delegate-in-swift-3-0-eafb2ec1113f

Comment: You can use [NotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use some model struct where you can add your score or any other data and easily manipulate it:

```
struct GameData{
    var totalScore: Int = 0
    var currentGameScore: Int = 0

    func invalidateCurrentScore(){
        totalScore += currentGameScore
        currentGameScore = 0
        //call this method when you need to set your current score to 0, and pass all the accumulated points to your total score (f.ex. in the end of the game)
    }

    //some other data like player's name and etc...
}
```

You also need to create a delegation protocol for using its method in ShopViewController and returning the game data to GameViewController:

```
protocol ShopViewControllerDelegate{
     func updateGameData(by gameData: GameData)
}
```

GameViewController with new parts:

```
class GameViewConroller: UIViewController, ShopViewControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    var gameData: GameData!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gameData = GameData()
        updateScoreLabel()
    }

    private func updateScoreLabel(){ //call it anyTime when you manipulate the score of current game
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(gameData.currentGameScore)"
    }

    func updateGameData(by gameData: GameData){ //This is the delegate's method that ShopViewController needs to trigger when you buy something in the shop
         self.gameData = gameData
         updateScoreLabel()
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, 
      sender: Any?){
        if let shopViewController = segue.destination as? ShopViewController{
            //passing game data to ShopViewController
            shopViewController.gameData = self.gameData
            shopViewController.delegate = self //!IMPORTANT
        }
    }
}
```

And these are some properties and methods that your ShopViewController should have:

```
class ShopViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var totalScoreLabel: UILabel!
    var gameData: GameData!
    var delegate: ShopViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateTotalScoreLabel()
    }
    private func updateTotalScoreLabel(){
        totalScoreLabel.text = "Total Score: \(gameData.totalScore + gameData.currentGameScore)"
    }

    private func purchasingSomething(){
        //logic of getting price of an item
        gameData.currentGameScore -= price
        if gameData.currentGameScore < 0{
            gameData.totalScore += gameData.currentGameScore
            gameData.currentGameScore = 0
            //if your current score is less than 0 after some purchase, your total score decreases and the current score becomes 0
        }
        updateTotalScoreLabel()
        delegate?.updateGameData(by gameData: gameData) //Pass refreshed gameData back to the GameViewController
    }
}
```

Also Swift has static variables, but it's very easy to use. Delegates bring more fun and makes code more pretty.

```
struct GameData{
    static var totalScore: Int = 0
    static var currentGameScore: Int = 0
}
```

Good luck and have fun with the game dev :)